# Creating random train and test data for sentiment analysis

Tags: python-2.7

How can I randomly divide my data into 3/4th of train data and 1/4th test data?

The train and test data should not contain repeated comments after the division.

Are there any packages in python that can be used?

Answer (score -1):

generate random numbers in particular range with the length(assume 10) of the data `order = random.sample(range(1,11),10)`, reshuffle the data with that

```
for i range(len(order)):
    newdata.append(olddata[order[i-1]])
```

and divide them

```
x_traindata = newdata[1:7] 
x_testdata  = newdata[7:]
```

Comment: This means that the first fold, `newdata[0]`, is neither present in the training nor in the test set. Also, your first block of code contains a syntax error!